# Ionic 2 Date Pipe adds hour

Tags: asp.net, date, ionic2

I've got a webservice which provide my app from data.
Currently I've got issues with dates.

In my Ionic pages i use the date pipe like this: 
{{model.DateStart | date: 'dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm'}}

This results in '18-02-2017 14:08', thats good.

But when the service sends this '2017-02-18T15:00:00' the result is '18-02-2017 16:00'.
That's not good.. It adds a hour somewhere.

It'll have to do with the locale settings somewhere, but I don't know how to fix it.

Anyone knows how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

After implementing [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) I get the result I want.